# Sending file and receiving response using ICAP and Java

Tags: java, http, icap

I'm trying to communicate with a Blue Coat anti-virus box using ICAP. I'm fairly new at Java, but i do have experience in other object-oriented languages.
I have tested using c-icap-client on Ubuntu and I can confirm that the server I'm testing with is working.

ICAP should be HTTP-like which explains the HTTP tag (not enough reputation for creating ICAP).

Does anyone have a tip or coding example to get me started with ICAP in Java? I want to end up sending a file and receiving a response based on it's security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured out myself. Both a Java and C# version is available from GitHub: https://github.com/Baekalfen/ICAP-avscan

Comment: Hi, I used the ICAP-avscan but it doesn't work  for me. I am trying to communicate to c-icap server and get error java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:132)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:88)
        at com.is.ICAP.sendBytes(ICAP.java:339)
        at com.is.ICAP.scanFile(ICAP.java:156)
        at com.is.VirusScanTest.main(VirusScanTest.java:18)

Comment: If other people see this, look at the Github thread: https://github.com/Baekalfen/ICAP-avscan/issues/3

Comment: I only created the issue :)